# Reading from EEPROM and combining

Tags: serial, softwareserial, eeprom

I'm trying to read from the EEPROM and combine the information and send it out over SoftwareSerial using write() function but i'm getting the following error

```
error: invalid operands of types 'const char [3]' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator+'
```

---

```
void loop()  
{ 
  const char* eTest1 = EEPROM.read(1);
  const char* eTest2 = EEPROM.read(2);
  const char* eTest3 = EEPROM.read(3);

  char combinedVal[] = eTest1+":"+eTest2+":"+eTest3;
  bluetooth.write(combinedVal);
}
```

Comment: btw: for a C string (char array terminated with 0), the `write` function is same as `print()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the + operator for that.

However, since EEPROM.read only returns one byte and not a string, you can do a much easier implementation:

```
void loop()  
{ 
  char result[] = "1:2:3";
  for (int item = 0; item < 3; item++)
  {
    result[item * 2] = EEPROM.read(1 + item);
  }
}
```

This first create a string "1:2:3", where the digits are overwritten in the for loop by that item. Note that the digits in the string do not matter, it's just some free 'comment', it also should work when using "x:x:x".

Comment: Ok thats great it trys to combined them but comes up with the following error                                 warning: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
     const char* eTest1 = EEPROM.read(1);
                                     ^

Comment: @Rickstar I made a better implementation, since EEPROM.read always returns exactly one byte (character).

Comment: @Rickstar EEPROM.read() returns one byte, not a pointer to string.

Comment: Thanks @MichelKeijzers

Comment: You're welcome.